# Laravel how to get query with bindings?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have some query that I need to pass to another query using query builder

```
$query = DB::table('table')->whereIn('some_field', [1,2,30])->toSql();

Model::join(DB::raw("({$query}) as table"), function($join) {
    $join->on('model.id', '=', 'table.id');
})
```

which should results with

```
Select * from model join (select * from table where some_field in (1,2,30)) as table on model.id = table.id
```

but the bindings are not passed, which force me to do

```
$query = DB::table('table')->whereRaw('some_field in ('. join(',', [1,2,30]) .')')->toSql();
```

what can be unsafe at times. How can I get the query with bindings?

Comment: Is `some_field` an integer? If so you could use `join(',', array_map('intval', [1,2,30]))` to make sure the array only contains integers.

Comment: Validation is not a case. Is more about code clarity.

Comment: You can use `toRawSql()` with Laravel 10 to get the whole query including the bindings

Answer (score 95):

**Update (July 2023):**

As of [Laravel 10.15.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v10.15.0) you can use `dumpRawSql()` or `ddRawSql()`

`DB::table('table')->whereIn('some_field', [1,2,3])->ddRawSql();`

**Original:**

Check out the `getBindings()` method on the `Builder` class

[getBindings()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getBindings)

```
$query = DB::table('table')->whereIn('some_field', [1,2,30]);

$sql = $query->toSql();

$bindings = $query->getBindings();
```

Comment: To get SQL with Bindings `$sql_with_bindings = str_replace_array('?', $query->getBindings(), $query->toSql());`

Comment: How do I favorite a comment? :D

Comment: Note that `str_replace_array()` is deprecated. Instead use the Str utility class: `use Illuminate\Support\Str; Str::replaceArray('?', $query->getBindings(), $query->toSql())`.

Comment: @EnnioSousa, this can be quite dangerous because the bindings `getBindings` gives are unescaped.

Comment: The propose is not make SQL query as output escaped and ready to be executed, if you're doing this, it is not recommended. The purpose is only get SQL with bindings to see raw query executed by Laravel.

Comment: @EnnioSousa there is no `str_replace_array()` function defined. I am confused.

Comment: @EnnioSousa please look at Soulriser's comment above concerning the str_replace_array() function

Comment: @androidu str_replace_array us deorecated, use Illuminate\Support\Str; Str::replaceArray() instead.

Answer (score 36):

Laravel now offers debugging directly on your Builder!!!

https://laravel.com/docs/queries#debugging

```php
\App\User::where('age', '18')->dump();
\App\User::where('age', '18')->dd();
```

Outputs

```php
"select * from `users` where `age` = ?"
[
    0 => "18"
]
```

Answer (score 29):

```
public static function getQueries(Builder $builder)
{
    $addSlashes = str_replace('?', "'?'", $builder->toSql());
    return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $addSlashes), $builder->getBindings());
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for

Comment: Turns out that the usage of '%s' will conflict with wildcards when using 'LIKE

Comment: Had the same issue. You can simply use `str_replace(['?', '%'], ["'?'", '%%'], $builder->toSql())`, that'll do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

You can define below code block as helper function and use wherever required.
It will bind numeric as well as string value with quotations.

```
public static function getSqlWithBindings($query)
{
    return vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query->toSql()), collect($query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
        return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
    })->toArray());
}
```

Example:

```
$query = Document::where('model', 'contact')->where('model_id', '1');
dd(Document::getSqlWithBindings($query));
```

Output:

```
"select * from `document` where `model` = 'contact' and `model_id` = 1"
```

Answer (score 6):

Building upon [Douglas.Sesar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721733/6871377)'s answer.

I found I also needed to put the bindings in single quotations to be able to easily paste it into my database IDE.

```php
$sql = $query->toSql();
$bindings = $query->getBindings();

$sql_with_bindings = preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function ($match) use ($sql, &$bindings) {
    return json_encode(array_shift($bindings));
}, $sql);
```

Comment: Hey I used this and I liked it - However, the quoting did not work well with FALSE - so I fixed it with `return json_encode(array_shift($bindings));` - I think I will make this edit.

Answer (score 5):

```
$sqlQuery = Str::replaceArray(
    '?',
    collect($query->getBindings())
        ->map(function ($i) {
            if (is_object($i)) {
                $i = (string)$i;
            }
            return (is_string($i)) ? "'$i'" : $i;
        })->all(),
    $query->toSql());
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function ensures the resulting SQL doesn't confuse bindings with columns by enclosing the `?`  to be `'?'`

```php
    public static function getFinalSql($query)
    {
        $sql_str = $query->toSql();
        $bindings = $query->getBindings();

        $wrapped_str = str_replace('?', "'?'", $sql_str);

        return str_replace_array('?', $bindings, $wrapped_str);
    }
```

Comment: It works but it does not escape the bindings, Could be problematic for some.

Comment: \Str::replaceArray use instead str_replace_array

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an executed query including bindings from the query log:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
\DB::table('table')->get();
dd(str_replace_array('?', \DB::getQueryLog()[0]['bindings'], 
      \DB::getQueryLog()[0]['query']));
```

Comment: One can loop  DB::getQueryLog() to get all queries with bindings op to that point! 
Thanks for this.

Comment: Very important! If you use a connection which is different from the default one, you must specify it using `DB::connection('myConn')->enableQueryLog();`.

Comment: Function `str_replace_array` is deprecated. You can use instead Str class utility: `\Str::replaceArray`

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers do not properly quote the expressions, here is my approach. It uses the escaping function that belongs to the current database connection.

It replaces the question marks one by one with the corresponding binding, which is retrieved from $bindings via array_shift(), consuming the array in the process. Note, that $bindings has to be passed by reference for this to work.

```
function getSql($query)
{
        $bindings = $query->getBindings();

        return preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function ($match) use (&$bindings, $query) {
            return $query->getConnection()->getPdo()->quote(array_shift($bindings));
        }, $query->toSql());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this function. It is partial, might be parameters which are not covered, for me it was enough.
More than welcomed to add your improvements in a comment!

```
function getFullSql($query) {
  $sqlStr = $query->toSql();
  foreach ($query->getBindings() as $iter=>$binding) {

    $type = gettype($binding);
    switch ($type) {
      case "integer":
      case "double":
        $bindingStr = "$binding";
        break;
      case "string":
        $bindingStr = "'$binding'";
        break;
      case "object":
        $class = get_class($binding);
        switch ($class) {
          case "DateTime":
            $bindingStr = "'" . $binding->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'";
            break;
          default:
            throw new \Exception("Unexpected binding argument class ($class)");
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new \Exception("Unexpected binding argument type ($type)");
    }

    $currentPos = strpos($sqlStr, '?');
    if ($currentPos === false) {
      throw new \Exception("Cannot find binding location in Sql String for bundung parameter $binding ($iter)");
    }

    $sqlStr = substr($sqlStr, 0, $currentPos) . $bindingStr . substr($sqlStr, $currentPos + 1);
  }

  $search = ["select", "distinct", "from", "where", "and", "order by", "asc", "desc", "inner join", "join"];
  $replace = ["SELECT", "DISTINCT", "\n  FROM", "\n    WHERE", "\n    AND", "\n    ORDER BY", "ASC", "DESC", "\n  INNER JOIN", "\n  JOIN"];
  $sqlStr = str_replace($search, $replace, $sqlStr);

  return $sqlStr;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the only thing that makes sense. I just don't get the last part, the problem I see there is that if I would have a column called `selected` in some table, it would say `SELECTed` after the conversion. Maybe it should be flagged with a `$pretify` parameter default to `false`, because in production I don't care how it looks ;)

Comment: Oh and I would add `case "boolean":` to `integer` and `double`. Natively integer 1 and boolean true are the same as in false and 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$escapedBindings = array();

foreach($query->getBindings() as $item) {$escapedBindings[] = '"'.$item.'"';}

$sql_with_bindings = Str::replaceArray('?', $escapedBindings, $query->toSql());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question (2015), but since this is the first Google result I got I think it's worth to give my solution as well, in case it's useful for the next person.

Eloquent (5.7 onwards I think, I haven't tested more recent or earlier versions) has a method to change a Builder's `from` to wrap a subquery:

```
# Taken from Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php - Line 272
public function fromSub($query, $as) {
    [$query, $bindings] = $this->createSub($query);

    return $this->fromRaw('('.$query.') as '.$this->grammar->wrapTable($as), $bindings);
}
```

This however requires an already existing instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. In order to make an empty one, you can do:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

$fancy = DB::table("videogames")->where("uses_sdl2", 1);
$empty = DB::table(null);

# Wrap the fancy query and set it as the "from" clause for the empty one
# NOTE: the alias is required
$empty = $empty->fromSub($fancy, "performant_games");
```

This will warranty that bindings are treated correctly, since they'll be handled by Eloquent itself.

Answer (score 2):

Raw Query Output With Bindings is Coming to Laravel 10 on the next tagged v10.x release (as of 7/3/2023).

Example:

```
User::where('email', 'foo@example.com')->toRawSql();
```

Which will then dump the following results:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'foo@example.com'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and elegant solution:

```
foreach (DB::getQueryLog() as $q) {
    $queryStr = \Str::replaceArray('?', $q['bindings'], $q['query']);
    echo $queryStr . ";\n";
}
```

(if you use a non-default connection, use `DB::connection('yourConn')->getQueryLog()` in the foreach command).

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 10** can [now](https://twitter.com/tobias_petry/status/1671129067905490944) return raw queries with bindings!

```php
User::where('email', 'foo@example.com')->toRawSql();
```

Answer (score 0):

Output to the log all queries with inserted bindings **sorted from the slowest query to the fastest**:

```
    \DB::enableQueryLog();

    // Put here your queries 
    $query = DB::table('table')->whereIn('some_field', [1,2,30]); 
    $query2 = DB::table('table2')->where('some_field', '=', 10); 


    $logQueries = \DB::getQueryLog();
    usort($logQueries, function($a, $b) {
        return $b['time'] <=> $a['time'];
    });

    foreach ($logQueries as $item) {
        \Log::info(str_replace_array('?', $item['bindings'], $item['query']));
        \Log::info($item['time']. ' ms');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code snippet to the `boot()` method in your `AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

public function boot()
{
    /// ......
    
    Builder::macro('sql', function () {
        $query = $this;
        $bindings = $query->getBindings();

        return preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function ($match) use (&$bindings, $query) {
            return $query->getConnection()->getPdo()->quote(array_shift($bindings));
        }, $query->toSql());
    });
}
```

After adding the code to the `boot()` method, you can utilize it in any query as follows:

```php
// Example usage:
Model::sql();
```

By following these steps, you'll be able to incorporate the provided code snippet into your `AppServiceProvider` file and utilize the `sql()` method in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution in Laravel 10 and later is to use `toRawSql()` instead of `toSql()` which prints the complete query including the bindings.

```php
$query = DB::table('table')->whereIn('some_field', [1,2,30])->toRawSql();

Model::join(DB::raw("({$query}) as table"), function($join) {
    $join->on('model.id', '=', 'table.id');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My generic solution for DB debugging is this:

```
DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) {
  $sql_with_bindings = Str::replaceArray('?', $query->bindings, $query->sql);
  Log::info(sprintf("SQL WITH DATA: %s", $sql_with_bindings));
});
```

Depending on you situation, you might consider adding a:

```
if (config('app.debug') == true) {
}
```

around this if you want to avoid debug logs in production...

Answer (score 0):

I have a little hack to view the actual running query

`User::where('id', 123)->first()`

just change the column name to break the query and you will see the complete query in the error

`User::where('ida', 123)->first()`

It will break the query and throw an error screen  you can see which query is running their

**Note: only for local development.**

fun fact you can do this in every framework

Answer (score -3):

It is all explained here..... 
https://ajcastro29.blogspot.com/2017/11/laravel-join-derived-tables-properly.html

I created a scope query for that thing. I think it can also be in macros..

```
public function scopeJoinDerived($query, $derivedQuery, $table, $one, $operator = null, $two = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false)
{
    $query->join(DB::raw("({$derivedQuery->toSql()}) as `{$table}`"), $one, $operator, $two, $type, $where);
    $join = last($query->getQuery()->joins);
    $join->bindings =  array_merge($derivedQuery->getBindings(), $join->bindings);

    return $query;
}
```