# Using whereIn with orWhere functions in Eloquent query

Tags: php, eloquent, where-in

I am struggling to add a `whereIn` to a more complex query:

```
      $events = Toolplan::query()
        ->select('id', 'eventId', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('start', '<=', $start)->whereDate('end', '>=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('end', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('start', '<=', $end);
        }) 
// gives "General error: 1096 No tables used":
        ->whereIn('eventId', function ($query) use ($eventIds){
           $query->whereIn('eventId', $eventIds);   
        })
// no effect: 
//      ->whereIn('eventId', $eventIds)
        ->get();
```

I tried to add it as a function and in simple form but the function leads to `General error: 1096 No tables used` and the other shows no effect at all, because the collection is far too large and should be only 4 items after `whereIn` and the `orWhere` selection. `$eventIds` is a flat array:

```
["P000018","P000054","P000021","P000030"]
```

Comment: you don't need to pass a function for your `whereIn`; if the result you are getting is too large then it's definitely a matter of grouping since you're using orWhere you need to get your `where`s grouped correctly to get the expected result

Comment: could you please give a short example? i would like to do the `whereIn` first then the `orWheres`. how to provide the first result to the `orWhere`query?

Comment: before you call `->get()`, you can call `->toSql()` and print the output, it's the generated query, you can verify if it contains the `where in` clause or not. your query is not much complex , it should work.

Comment: @MajedDH Thanks, this is helpful but I have a question: When I replace `->get()` for `->toSql()` in the above query, `$start`, `$end` and `$eventIds` are replaced with `?` in the Sql printout, e.g. it prints `eventId in (?, ?, ?, ?)` for the `whereIn` (while result of 4 items is correct). How can I make these variables visible in the Sql printout?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314506/laravel-how-to-get-query-with-bindings