# Laravel Eloquent bad building query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I built an Eloquent query like the following.

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$reportSelect = Payment::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'payment.user_id')
    ->join('user_information', 'user_information.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('register_type', 'register_type.id', '=', 'payment.register_type_id')
    ->join('payment_type', 'payment_type.id', '=', 'payment.payment_type_id')
    ->select(
        'payment.id',
        'user_information.full_name as user_full_name',
        'register_type.register_type',
        'payment_type.payment_type',
        'payment.created_at',
        'payment.updated_at'
    );

$date_start = '2021-7-6';
$date_end = '2021-7-10';

$reportSelect->whereBetween('payment.created_at', [$date_start, $date_end])->get();

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();

return $queries;
```

The result of this SQL query log is the following.

```
SELECT
    'payment'.'id',
    'user_information'.'full_name' as 'user_full_name',
    'register_type'.'register_type',
    'payment_type'.'payment_type',
    'payment'.'created_at',
    'payment'.'updated_at'
FROM 'payment'
    inner join 'users' on 'users'.'id' = 'payment'.'user_id'
    inner join 'user_information' on 'user_information'.'user_id' = 'users'.'id'
    inner join 'register_type' on 'register_type'.'id' = 'payment'.'register_type_id'
    inner join 'payment_type' on 'payment_type'.'id' = 'payment'.'payment_type_id'
WHERE 'payment'.'created_at' between ? and ?
```

Why not set in the where clause my `date_start` param and `date_end` param, instead it puts the character `?`. Thanks in advance; sorry for my English.

Comment: That is normal, this is how Laravel shows your query, `?` means a value is going to be replaced/binded there.

Comment: in others select query "?" doesn appears and the ? character is the cause that the query doesn works

Comment: Check [this answer & its first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721733/7117697).

Answer (score 0):

//You need to add date method with $date_start and $date_end

$date_start = date('2021-7-6');
$date_end = date('2021-7-10');

$reportSelect->whereBetween('payment.created_at', [$date_start, $date_end])->get();